# How to override /Token api call behaviour in ASP.NET Web API Application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity, asp.net-authorization

I have an ASP.NET Web API Application and I'm trying to make my API calls secure and only available to registered users.

I know that a registered user can get an access token by invoking /Token and sending a username and password and grant_type along with a request.

I understand this all happens because of the following configuration inside `Startup.Auth.cs` file in `App_start` folder :

```
OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
{
    TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/Token"),
    Provider = new ApplicationOAuthProvider(PublicClientId),
    AuthorizeEndpointPath = new PathString("/api/Account/ExternalLogin"),
    AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(14),
    // In production mode set AllowInsecureHttp = false
    AllowInsecureHttp = true
};
```

Normally calling /Token with a username and password, would search the default users table and if that user exists then it sends the access token to the user.

However in my project i have my own method/table to register users and store them in the database. So I'm not using the default users table provided by ASP.NET Identity.

#### Question:

Is it possible for me to somehow override/change how a request to /Token is handled? So in there I can check the username/password through my own custom users table and then send the access token if everything was ok.

#### Edit:

I thought of a way but I really doubt that it should be the way to go. In my own custom method for registering users, when everything is fine i can make a call to

```
var user = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };
IdentityResult result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
if (!result.Succeeded)
{
    // Return error
}

// Return success
```

And now my users are in the ASP.NET Users table as well and subsequent calls to /Token should recognize them as registered users. But I figure now I have duplicated my users in two tables. Is there any clean way to achieve what i want?

Comment: IMO, you can try creating a custom `ApplicationOAuthProvider` class, then inside `public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)`, use your custom code instead of `ApplicationUser user = await userManager.FindAsync(context.UserName, context.Password);`

Comment: @BNK, I see. To make things simpler, in the `ApplicationOAuthProvider.cs file`, in the `public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)` method, can i just change this line `ApplicationUser user = await userManager.FindAsync(context.UserName, context.Password);` to my own custom code to find a registered user? Does that mean a request to /Token is always going through this method to find if a username/password is registered?

Comment: I think so, however, you should test to make sure it works, perhaps setting a breakpoint there and debugging :)